# Tomcat 6 only localhost returns 200, from another box via IP connects but returns 403?

Tags: tomcat, ubuntu, tomcat6

Im trying to set up the blackberry push server, which runs within tomcat 6. The installer for this has executed fine, everything is up and running as expected.

However, I can only connect to it from the local machine, which I can prove using links or wget from the box. So, localhost:8080 returns the default Tomcat page as expected, and the web manager etc are running fine.

As soon as I try to connect to this via the ip, eg, http://ipaddress:8080 this connects to Tomcat but returns a 403, showing -

> description Access to the specified resource () has been forbidden.

And this is been logged.

Therefore it looks like this is not a network issue but a Tomcat configuration issue. Ive been reading through the docs and feel like im overlooking something stupidly easy here. I have tried

1. `<Alias>ipaddresshere</Alias>` to server.xml, under the locathost `<Host>`
2. Tried changing the name attribute of the `<Host>` section.
3. Adding a separate `<Host>` section with name being the IP address

I am running shutdown.sh then startup.sh after each change, and these are coming up clean.

Here is my server.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
```

```
  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
```

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->

```
<!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more named thread pools-->
<!--
<Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-" 
    maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
-->


<!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
     and responses are returned. Documentation at :
     Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html (blocking & non-blocking)
     Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
     APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
     Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
-->
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           redirectPort="8443" useBodyEncodingForURI="true" />
<!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
<!--
<Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
           port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           redirectPort="8443" />
-->           
<!-- Define a SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
     This connector uses the JSSE configuration, when using APR, the 
     connector should be using the OpenSSL style configuration
     described in the APR documentation -->
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true" 
           keystoreFile="keystores/.keystore" keystorePass="changeit" 
       clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" useBodyEncodingForURI="true"/>


<!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />


<!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
     every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
     analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
     on to the appropriate Host (virtual host).
     Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->

<!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">         
--> 
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

  <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
      /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
      /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
  <!--
  <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
  -->        

  <!-- The request dumper valve dumps useful debugging information about
       the request and response data received and sent by Tomcat.
       Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
  <!--
  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestDumperValve"/>
  -->

  <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
       resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
       that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
       available for use by the Realm.  -->
  <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
         resourceName="UserDatabase"/>

  <!-- Define the default virtual host
       Note: XML Schema validation will not work with Xerces 2.2.
   -->
  <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
        xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
<Alias>IPADDRESSHERE</Alias>
<Alias>CL-Blackberry</Alias>
    <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
         Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
    <!--
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
    -->

    <!-- Access log processes all example.
         Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->

    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"  
           prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt" pattern="common" resolveHosts="true"  />

  </Host>
</Engine>
```

This server is only for internal network use.

Can anyone spot here im going wrong here, again im convinced its a tomcat configuration thing. Im running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS with all the latest updates via apt.

Comment: 403 is an authorization failure - is the web.xml for the webapp you're trying to access available online somewhere, or the entire tomcat bundle (can you link to them, or a Blackberry page where we can following along?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always seem to find a solution once Ive asked here on SO!

Anyway, It was a case of adding a second `<Host>` along with localhost. This didnt work the first time around and im not sure why, maybe Tomcat didnt come back up clean after this change.

So, adding this below localhost:

```
<Host name="10.100.9.170" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autodeploy="true" xmlValidation="false" >
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"  
           prefix="10-100-9-170_access_log." suffix=".txt" pattern="common" resolveHosts="true"  />
  </Host>
```

Did the trick.